# Regular Expression to Isolate a String of Characters in the proper context

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing

So, I have a dashboard which I'm currently writing (PHP). The idea is that it is supposed to display data in a database relative to a given url specified. If the user wishes to just grab everything, they simply need to specify "all". If they wish to scrape data for specific URLs AND display everything at once, they will specify additional URLs *with* the "all" directive.

I discovered a bug, however.

If I have a URL which has the characters "all" in it (such as, say, `http://everythingallatonce.com` <-- that's just an example - I have no idea if that actually exists), the dashboard's parsing algorithm which takes the instruction given won't work properly. In fact, according to this logic, it will think that the user specified a given URL as well AS the words "all", without actually checking off the "perform scrape?" checkbox, which makes no sense at all (hence, it just throws an exception/dies with an error message).

So far, I just have a function like the following:

```
function _strExists( $needle, $haystack )
{
     $pos = strpos( $haystack, $needle );

     return ( $pos !== false );
}
```

Which I use to detect to see if the word "all" exists in the query, like so:

`$fetchEverything = _strExists('all', $urls);`

**What would be a good work around for something like this, to avoid ambiguity between URLs specified which have "all" in them, and the actual query of *all* by itself?** I'm thinking regular expressions, but I'm not sure...

**Also**

I have considered just using `*`, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate more on how your script is being called? I.e. give an example request?

Answer (score 0):

If some value for `all` is being passed in the URL (i.e. all=1). Then you should look in the `$_GET` superglobal for it's existence (i.e. `$_GET['all']`)

Comment: It's actually being passed through `$_POST`. I try to avoid `$_GET` where possible...